# HTML Firefox - Dotted outline/border on checked/focus option in a "listbox" <select multiple='multiple'><option>

Tags: html, css, firefox, select, focus

I'm working with Firefox 84.0.2 (64-bit) and the normal solution for removing the dotted outline is not working properly.

CSS usual solution that's not working!

```
:focus {outline:none !important;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0 !important;}
```

Was there any changes to Firefox to forbid the removal of this?

Answer (score -1):

@Cranky Unicorn, you should use this line of code —> "outline = none, border = none"

Comment: I did, no luck with that.